# C# removing the current item in a listbox

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I have a List which holds a bunch of objects, the contents of the list is then added to a listbox control. My question is, how can I remove the current item in the list which will in turn remove the current item in the listbox?

Comment: WPF or WinForms?  Please edit the question and add the tag

Comment: @Merlyn have you ever saw a noob user that asks a C# GUI question without saying its about WPF that actually turned out to be WPF question? its winforms!

Comment: @Nahum: Whether you are correct or not, Dan should add it to his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just get the selected index in the selectedindex_changed event handler, remove the object at that index and repopulate the listbox

```
int index = listbox.SelectedIndex();
listThatHoldsObjects.RemoveAt(index); 
listbox.ItemsSource = listThatHoldsObjects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `BindingList<object>` to bind it to the list and associate the list of object `List<object>` with this `BindingList`. Once you remove an item from `BindingList` it will remove the same item from both `List` and `ListBox`

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.Add("test");
list.Add("test1");

BindingList<object> bindingList;
bindingList = new BindingList<object>(list);            

listBox1.DataSource = bindingList;

bindingList.Remove("test");
```

Comment: It's even easier to remove selected items...
bindingList.Remove(listBox1.SelectedValue);

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `BindingList<T>` class ([found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)) and bind it to the `ListBox`.

If you do not want that, you can always use:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.RemoveAt(lb.SelectedIndex);
lb.Items.RemoveAt(lb.SelectedIndex);
```