# Remove selected item from generic list via a button and listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, generic-list

How can you remove from a generic list via a button with the selected item in a listbox?

This is what I have so far in my button click method:

```
if (listBox2.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(listBox2.SelectedItem);
            listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItem);
            if (listBox2.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listBox2.GetSelected(i) == true)
                    {
                        Foods m = listBox2.SelectedItem as Foods;
                        list.Remove(m);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I assumed the line

> list.Remove(m);

would do it but it does not do anything.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Yes I have, sadly it did not work

Comment: What about solution in this thread ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377390/c-sharp-removing-the-current-item-in-a-listbox

Comment: try adding list.Contains(m) before calling Remove to check if it is the right item that you are trying to remove

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Have given it a go but again it doesn't work and the final line with the ItemsSource gives me an error.

Comment: Can you post other part of the code?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Which part?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad That was an error on my part sorry was meant to be listbox2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are removing the SelectedItem before finding it in the `for` loop. Not sure but this may helps:

```
if (listBox2.Items.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listBox2.GetSelected(i) == true)
        {
            Foods m = chosenBox.SelectedItem as Foods;
            list.Remove(m);
        }
    }
}

listBox1.Items.Add(listBox2.SelectedItem);
listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hello dear use the simple code and solve your query.....**

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
         if (this.listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)

        this.listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(this.listBox1.SelectedIndex);

    }
```